# Using openfl-gpg and openfl-gps-lib, missing AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: android, google-play-services, android-manifest, haxe, haxepunk

I'm trying to use *openfl-gpg* and *openfl-gps-lib* to use Google Play Services in my HaxePunk game.
Unfortunately when I try to build, I get the following error:

```
BUILD FAILED
E:\Development\Android SDK\tools\ant\build.xml:577: com.android.io.StreamException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: E:\PROJETS\Tarmac\TMM\bin\android\bin\deps\google-play-services_lib\AndroidManifest.xml (Le fichier spécifié est introuvable)
    at com.android.io.FileWrapper.getContents(FileWrapper.java:93)
    at com.android.xml.AndroidManifest.getStringValue(AndroidManifest.java:410)
    at com.android.xml.AndroidManifest.getPackage(AndroidManifest.java:146)
    at com.android.ant.ComputeDependencyTask$1.processLibrary(ComputeDependencyTask.java:198)
    at com.android.ant.DependencyHelper$AdvancedLibraryProcessor.processLibrary(DependencyHelper.java:69)
    at com.android.ant.DependencyHelper.processLibraries(DependencyHelper.java:210)
    at com.android.ant.GetLibraryPathTask.execute(GetLibraryPathTask.java:183)
    at com.android.ant.GetLibraryPathTask.execute(GetLibraryPathTask.java:162)
    at com.android.ant.ComputeDependencyTask.execute(ComputeDependencyTask.java:226)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1393)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1364)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1248)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:851)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:235)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: E:\PROJETS\Tarmac\TMM\bin\android\bin\deps\google-play-services_lib\AndroidManifest.xml (Le fichier spécifié est introuvable)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:120)
    at com.android.io.FileWrapper.getContents(FileWrapper.java:91)
    ... 24 more

Total time: 0 seconds
Build halted with errors.
```

I tried to put an empty *AndroidManifest.xml* where it is missing, but I just get another error. So I'm guessing I'm doing something wrong, but I don't know what.

Any idea?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Why don't you copy that error message to your question instead of providing a picture?

Comment: Sorry I only had my gyazo shot I did for twitter when I posted.

Comment: Go to Eclipse --> Window --> Preferences and set your working location for Android SDK properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should post this directly on the project GitHub page (under issues). Anyway, did you downloaded the google play services lib from your android SDK manager?

Note that you need to do that (https://github.com/SempaiGames/openfl-gpg#how-to-install). You also should make sure you're using openfl-legacy for now (as openfl-next does not support android extensions yet).